# How to bring-up PCI passthrough for NIC card in ubuntu ARM based system

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, pci, pci-passthrough

I have Intel x700 series NIC card on my ubuntu 22.04[ARM] based system

And using KVM for virtualization, I need to use these NIC ports for guest VMs.

If any document to setup PCI passthrough for NIC card would be better and i have followed the following URL to setup. But unfortunately didn't work out.

> https://www.servethehome.com/how-to-pass-through-pcie-nics-with-proxmox-ve-on-intel-and-amd/

In this document after setting all i don't see any output on below command.

```
root@a1-95910:/home/ixuser# **cat /etc/default/grub**
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet intel_iommu=on iommu=pt"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""


root@a1-95910:/home/ixuser# **cat /etc/modules**
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.
vfio
vfio_iommu_type1
vfio_pci
vfio_virqfd
root@a1-95910:/home/ixuser# **dmesg | grep -e DMAR -e IOMMU**
root@a1-95910:/home/ixuser#
```

It looks like this document is for intel and AMD based device.

Any support is more helpful.